# How do I run the integrated video adaptor alongside the GPU on an intel?

Tags: graphics-card, intel-graphics

I've got an Asus P8Z77 motherboard with a core i7 3770 processor, and a Geforce 660 video card. I'm running Windows 8.

While I primarily use the latter, there's situations where I want to use the HD4000 video adaptor built into the core processor - for example where I want to take advantage of quicksync. How would I do this?

Comment: I'd add that with recent driver versions, having a monitor plugged in is NOT needed for quicksync use. However, the answer still holds true if you want to use the iGPU for output alongside a dGPU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the iGPU Multi-Monitor setting under advanced/system agent configuration/graphics configuration needs to be turned on. This is labelled for being for [virtu](http://www.lucidlogix.com/product-virtu-gpu.html) but is necessary for the integrated GPU to be detectable by windows, even if you arn't running virtu. This setting is still around on more modern intel systems - with my z390 and 9th generation intel processor its still an available option, and it worked exactly the same on my old box through windows 8-10

On my Asus Z77 board the option looked something like this

[image: Screenshot of Bios page]

Obviously the location of this may vary with different motherboard brands and the name of the setting may be different.

My guess is since lucid logix uses both GPUs, it tells the motherboard to simply run both - independent of whether you're running more than one monitor (with lucid outputting what you're rendering on the dedicated GPU to the integrated GPU), or using a multi-monitor set up taking advantage of both the IGPU and Dedicated GPU as independant outputs without lucid.

In my case this let me use my onboard video for a theoretical  3 *additional* outputs, rather than the switching that lucid does, and use quicksync alongside my discrete card.