# Dual monitors with integrated and discrete graphics card

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard

I'm trying to run dual monitors, one monitor using the VGA output in my integrated graphics card on my FOXCONN H55M-S motherboard, and the other on my nVidia Geforce GT 440.
After some tinkering I found out that I need to access the BIOS and choose one of the following on the primary graphics boot device:

- IGD
- PCI/IGD
- PCI/PEG
- PEG/IGD
- PEG/PCI (my default)

I'm picking PEG/IGD, which I assume is what's correct, but it still isn't working. After I boot it up, I plug in the monitor and it goes into sleep mode (from what I can tell, it receives a signal, it just doesn't "work").

There's nothing wrong with either monitor; I've alternated between them. What can I do to get my dual monitors to work?

Comment: Rather specific to the significantly newer ivy bridge series, but http://superuser.com/questions/523928/how-do-i-run-the-integrated-video-adaptor-alongside-the-gpu-on-a-ivy-ridge-syste might be of interest.

Answer (score -2):

It's and either/or situation. You typically can't use dual monitors across integrated graphics AND a graphics card. This is because the BIOS recognises the graphics card selects it as the device to display the screen. This is so the CPU (which renders the integrated graphics) can be left to do what it does best and the GPU then does what it does best.

This is a feature of the motherboard and can't be switched off as far as I know. If you want dual monitor support...

- Use dual monitors on integrated graphics (if supported)
- Install a graphics card with dual monitor support
- Install 2 graphics cards with single monitor support.

**Update:**
While SOME mobo's can enable integrated graphics with an external graphics card (e.g. https://communities.intel.com/thread/42192) but from my research, the mobo has to be able to set the integrated graphics as the default. Unfortunately, your particular model doesn't enable integrated graphics as the default, only as a fall back. So what I said still stands.

Comment: Incorrect.  You typically *can* use both the integrated video as well as an additional video card.

Comment: Really? How do you do it? All my experiences say that typically you can't. The mobo seems to always want to get the load off the CPU if it can.

Comment: Typically by default the onboard graphics are enabled out of the box.  if you add a second video card, Windows will want to install the drivers for it after it is detected on that first boot, but the onboard graphics chipset is still active in device manager.  At that point, it is typically just a matter of enabling specific dual monitor settings within Windows (cloned or extended desktop, etc).  Normally, you have to specifically disable onboard graphics within the BIOS to use one **or** the other.