# Asus Z97 Mark 2, i7-4790 getting CPU graphics to work

Tags: cpu, motherboard, graphics

This is a new build.  I've been trying for two days to get the CPU integrated graphics to work.  The motherboard has a "displayport" connector which I have connected to my Asus PA246Q monitor, also with provision for the displayport connector.  I've tried setting the UEFI to each of the positions.  I've run out of options here, and I'm just wondering if anyone else has had a similar experience and how they overcame it it -- if at all.

Comment: Do you have a discrete video card? Could you check if there's something called ["iGPU Multi-Monitor"](http://superuser.com/questions/523928/how-do-i-run-the-integrated-video-adaptor-alongside-the-gpu-on-a-ivy-bridge-syst/523929#523929)?

Comment: Between and around installing drivers and peripherals I've needed a way to monitor the steps, so I've been temporarily sticking in a Radeon AX4350 1GBD2-H.  I've tried the bios selection for exclusive output via the displayport, and to make sure that it's triggered, I've tried this with the Radeon card removed entirely.  Zilch.  So is the "iGPU Multi-Monitor" a selection in the BIOS?  I'm not sure what you mean otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, its  BIOS option used to let you run itegrated graphics and discrete cards at once.

Comment: Yes, there is a reference in the bios graphics selection to this, and I've tried running the multi-monitor mode.  I didn't test it with the discrete graphics card removed because it wouldn't make sense if that were a requirement of using the CPU graphics.  Nevertheless, if I view the display options, I can set my system for monitor 1 or monitor 2, which suggests that the onboard CPU graphics are functional.  Still I'm making these observations through monitor 1 because no matter what I do, I'm not able to remove the graphics card and view monitor 2 independently.

Comment: BTW, when I refer to "monitor 2", the selection shown in Win 7's display settings actually refers to it as "2. Display device on: VGA".  I have been presuming this means the signal coming from the displayport on the MOBO.

Comment: I guess we can consider this unsolved.  My best observation is that the "displayport" (this is the correct syntax) is either non-functional or so poorly orchestrated in the BIOS settings that it's rendered unusable.  And despite my best intentions, I guess I'm back to the graphics card.