# 2nd display in a dual display set up won't has no input signal

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, displayport

Brand new Dell OptiPlex 9020 - Core i7 4790 3.6 GHz desktop https://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Dell-OptiPlex-9020-Core-i7-4790-3.6-GHz-8-GB-500-GB/3851732.aspx?pfm=reo#PO and 2 Viewsonic 22' display monitors.  The Dell has a VGA and 2 displayport connections to the motherboard.  It also has a DVI connection to the GPU.  The Viewsonics have DVI and VGA outputs.
The first display is connected to the motherboard's VGA port and works fine.
I tried connecting the second display to the GPU's DVI port but got no signal. Added a DVI to Displayport adaptor and connected it to the motherboard's Displayport and still have no signal.  Does a function need to be changed on the computer or do I need to download/update drivers for the display to read?  I believe it should be plug n play, so not sure why I'm having this no signal issue.

Comment: "Brand new": tells us nothing What's the desktop, what chipset does its motherboard use, and what's the GPU? http://superuser.com/questions/523928/how-do-i-run-the-integrated-video-adaptor-alongside-the-gpu-on-a-ivy-bridge-syst might be the same situation but there's not enough information to tell

Comment: Added the model of the computer and the link to all relevant information regarding it.  The GPU is an AMD Radeon R7.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to use to different GPU sources at one time. You're trying to utilize the integrated and dedicated graphics at once. You need to either use two display ports from the motherboards integrated graphics, or two display ports from the dedicated GPU. Based on the information you gave, it sounds like the GPU only has one DVI port and that's it. So in order to use dual monitors, you'll have to a combination of two ports from the integrated graphics.

Comment: this actually works on some chipsets

Comment: @DrZoo Thanks.  So I tried using 2 ports on the integrated graphics card on the motherboard, the VGA, which worked and the displayport which didn't work, when using a DVI to Displayport adaptor.  I did some more research and think it may have to do with the displayport adaptor as it needs to be "active" not "passive".  And/or it could be that the DVI connector isn't the right type, which probably needs to be DVI-D.

Comment: @climbingthetree if you can give an exact model of your PC I can help you look into it

Comment: Thanks!  Here's the model which includes a picture of the back panel: https://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Dell-OptiPlex-9020-Core-i7-4790-3.6-GHz-8-GB-500-GB/3851732.aspx?pfm=reo  Looks like the GPU has a DVI-I connector.

Comment: @climbingthetree it looks like your dedicated GPU has a DisplayPort and a DVI-I ports. Have you tried running dual monitor off of those? After you've done that, have you ensured that the display settings are set to extend your desktop? Also check to ensure that the input settings for your monitors are on the correct input settings.

Comment: I tried every combination of inputs possible including using adapters, etc.  I also downloaded the latest GPU driver and checked the display drivers, which were already up to date.  The problem was the 2nd display wouldn't show up as a display on the computer so I couldn't modify the settings and I verified that both displays worked by switching the inputs.  Ultimately I found out it was a BIOS setting.